# Promise: Then before Resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, aws-lambda

Very first thing I've ever done in Node.js, I'm writing an AWS Lambda function, and I want to check whether a custom attribute on a User has a value before doing anything else. Since I'm told Promises are the way to handle asynchronous methods synchronously, I wrote the function:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var cogId = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

exports.handler = function (event, context) {

    if (event != null)
    {
        var identityId = context.identity.cognitoIdentityId;

        if (event.userId != null)
        {
            var userId = event.userId;
            PromiseConfirmIdNotSet(userId)
                .then(SetId(userId, identityId))
                .catch();
        }
    }

    context.done(null, 'Hello World');  // SUCCESS with message
};

function PromiseConfirmIdNotSet(userId)
{
    console.log('Entering function');
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log('Entering Promise');
        cogId.adminGetUser({
                UserPoolId: myUserPool,
                UserId: userId
            },
            function (err, data) {
                console.log('err = ' + JSON.stringify(err));
                console.log('data = ' + JSON.stringify(err));
                if (data != null && data.UserAttributes.Name == null) {
                    console.log('Calling resolve');
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    console.log('Calling reject');
                    reject();
                }
            });
    });
    console.log('Exiting Promise');
}

function SetId(userId, identityId)
{
    cogId.updateUserAttributes();
}
```

But when I run it, the console log shows "Entering function", then "Entering Promise", then the execution goes to `SetId` without ever having called the callback specified in `adminGetUser`.

If I let the debugger continue after the main flow is done, eventually I do get the logs from the callback function, so it does eventually run.

Why is the Promise skipping to the then without the `resolve` ever getting called?

Comment: Can you include the log output you're getting vs. the log output you're expecting? Also, the new ECMA spec has a new syntax for asynchronous functions (supported in AWS Lambda for Node.js 8.10) that you might want to investigate, since it makes the code a little cleaner: `async`/`await`: https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 5):

`.then` accepts a *function* as an argument. When you do

```
PromiseConfirmIdNotSet(userId)
  .then(SetId(userId, identityId))
  .catch();
```

`PromiseConfirmIdNotSet` is called, and *synchronously*, `SetId` is called, while the interpreter tries to construct a `Promise` chain from the function passed to `.then`. (But `SetId` doesn't return a function) Then, after that, `PromiseConfirmIdNotSet`'s asynchronous code runs, and the `Promise` resolves - which isn't in the order you want.

Change it so that `SetId` is only called *after* the promise returned by `PromiseConfirmIdNotSet` resolves:

```
PromiseConfirmIdNotSet(userId)
  .then(() => SetId(userId, identityId))
  .catch();
```

The problem is similar to why

```
addEventListener('click', fn());
```

doesn't work - you'd change it to `, fn);` or `, () => fn());`.

If you additionally want `context.done` to occur only after a successful `SetId`, then put the `context.done` call inside the `.then`:

```
PromiseConfirmIdNotSet(userId)
  .then(() => {
    SetId(userId, identityId);
    context.done(null, 'Hello World');  // SUCCESS with message
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! That mostly seems to work, though I expected the main thread to halt at the `then()`. Instead it ran through the `PromiseConfirmIdNotSet` function as expected and then continued out the end of the main function; the callback eventually fired sometime after the main execution had finished (and revealed that apparently I'm not giving the adminGetUser the right data, but that's another matter). Is there something else I need to do to get the main thread to wait for the Promise chain to finish execution?

Comment: are you saying that `context.done(null, 'Hello World');` before it should be? if so, that's because it's not at all part of the *Promise chain* so naturally doesn't *wait*

Comment: @Trevortni See edit, but the current thread will never pause inside a block like that unless it comes across an `await` inside an `async` function.

Comment: Correct. Like I said, this is my first time with Node.js, so I'm really not sure what I should expect to happen, but I was under the impression that the program would wait for the chain to complete. If that's not the case, then.... I suppose that's okay, as long as it doesn't matter if there are still threads running when the main thread ends. I don't think I actually need to return anything back to the caller for this function, but I am curious what I should do if that was needed; could the final piece in the chain return a value, maybe?

Comment: @Trevortni Javascript is single-threaded - there will only ever be one particular section of code that the interpreter is moving through at any given time. If another thread is spawned, like with `setTimeout`, that will only start running once the current thread is finished.

Comment: @Trevortni If you needed for the `Promise` to resolve to a value and use that value, then you would give the `.then` callback an argument. `.then((arg) => { /* do stuff with arg */`

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use async-await for neat asynchronous functions. Here is your code with async await. Please check and let me know if you find any more issues.

```
exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
 if (event != null)
 {
   var identityId = context.identity.cognitoIdentityId;

   if (event.userId != null)
   {
     var userId = event.userId;
     await PromiseConfirmIdNotSet(userId);
     await SetId(userId, identityId);
   }
 }

 await context.done(null, 'Hello World');  // SUCCESS with message
};

function PromiseConfirmIdNotSet(userId)
{
  console.log('Entering function');
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  console.log('Entering Promise');
  cogId.adminGetUser({
    UserPoolId: myUserPool,
    UserId: userId
  },
  function (err, data) {
    console.log('err = ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    console.log('data = ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    if (data != null && data.UserAttributes.Name == null) {
        console.log('Calling resolve');
        resolve();
    } else {
      console.log('Calling reject');
      reject();
    }
  });
});
 console.log('Exiting Promise');
}

function SetId(userId, identityId)
{
  cogId.updateUserAttributes();
}
```